# Are there any side effects to Force Speed?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

If Force Speed accelerates the body, does this mean that the body also ages faster when it's in use? Can it be used to increase one's metabolism and to heal minor wounds?

Comment: Do people *normally* age faster when accelerating (barring relativity)?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming it works like it did in DC universe, I remember that a Flash counterpart went so fast that he accelerated to his death.

Comment: @NeoHerakles That's Speed Force....not Force Speed. Different universe....this is a Star Wars question.

Comment: I understand that but I have yet to see any detailed guide on the Force Abilities, the closest I've got is the Book of Sith but it just details Dark Side powers, along with Push and Pull.